# Magento: How do I list the values of a product's attribute set?

Tags: magento, attributes, product

In Magento (1.6 community edition), how do I find the values of a product's attribute set?

For example, there's a product with an Attribute Set called T-shirts, with attributes of Gender, Shirt Size, and Color. Starting with a $_product object, how do I find the values of the attributes, e.g. Mens, Green, Large?

Comment: you can try for dropdown attribute `$_product->getAttributeText('attributename')` or for simple attribute you can get like `$_product->getAttributeName()`

Comment: This works, but requires the attribute name to be known ahead of time:`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('gender')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product));`

Comment: How can I iterate over the attribute set to get all of their values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($_product->getAttributeSetId());
foreach($attributes as $_attribute){
    var_dump($_product->getData($_attribute['code']));
}
```

Comment: Rather than the values of the attribute set, this only picked up the "Model" field's value. The attribute set has a scope of Global, so I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: i understand what you mean, please check the revised answer

Comment: This answer does not produce the expected results.